# single-row subquery returns more than one row while update

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

While updating a query i get this error single-row subquery returns more than one row here is my update query

```
UPDATE GT_POLICY GP SET (ERP_POLICY_NO,ERP_INSERT_DATE,ERP_CUSTOMER_ID) = (SELECT ERP.POLICY_NUMBER,ERP.ISSUE_DATE,ERP.MDM_ID FROM ERP_POLICY_DETAILS ERP WHERE GP.ALTERNATE_POLICY_NO=ERP.ALT_POL_NO AND ERP.ALT_POL_NO LIKE 'POL%') WHERE GP.ERP_POLICY_NO IS NULL AND GP.RECORD_STATUS='Y';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for help due to duplicate alternate_policy_no i faced above issue but after putting below line query work properly

```
UPDATE ERP_POLICY_DETAILS ERP SET (DUPLICATE_FLAG)=
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ERP_POLICY_DETAILS ERP1 WHERE ERP.ALT_POL_NO = ERP1.ALT_POL_NO AND ERP.ALT_POL_NO LIKE 'POL%'
  GROUP BY  ALT_POL_NO);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the subquery by itself to determine the number of rows returned? Perhaps `GP.ALTERNATE_POLICY_NO = ERP.ALT_POL_NO` is returning more than one row.